# How to integrate AD with AWS.CloudFront

Tags: azure, amazon-s3, single-sign-on, amazon-cloudfront, identity-management

We have several learning materials hosted in S3 bucket, we want to intergrate our AD so that internal users can authenticate and access the content in the s3. How can I do this

I need to find a way to intergrate AD with S3 for our internal users to have access to our  several learning materials hosted in S3 bucket, we want to intergrate our AD so that internal users can authenticate and access the content in the s3. How can I do this

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.